# Aerospike Indexes Regeneration

Tags: aerospike

How does Aerospike regenrates indexes from stored data because it does not store actual key anywhere instead it just stores hash of (namespace, set, PK) hence once this hashtable goes down , how can it recreate it.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. There is nothing in the indexes that is not stored... The actual key is not the indexes either, just the hash. So the hash that is persistently stored will be reloaded in memory and that's how the primary index will be regenerated.

Answer (score 2):

Each record has a 64B metadata entry in the [primary index](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/primary-index.html). That same metadata is also stored on disk, unless you declared the namespace as [in-memory without persistence](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/namespace/storage#storage-engine-configuration-recipes). For example, each time you change the record's TTL, that metadata is written to disk, and not just modified in the primary index. The 20B digest (the record's unique key) is part of that [metadata](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/primary-index.html#index-metadata).

So when you're performing a [cold start](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/aerospike/cold_start), Aerospike scans the storage devices and rebuilds the entry in the primary-index from the record's metadata.